# Asp.net MVC project when using Chrome doesn't wait the methods return in debug mode

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, debugging, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2017

In the Asp.net MVC project when using Chrome doesn't wait the method return in debug mode, but when I run in IE,MS Edge debug performe well.  I verified the javascript debug option was cheked in VS.  It was working before, I don't know if there was a VS update that could have caused it. Do you have

Visual Studio 2017 Version 15.9.17
Google Chrome Version 84.0.4147.89 64 bits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Asp.net MVC project when using Chrome doesn't wait the methods return
> in debug mode

Please try the following steps:

**1)** close VS, delete `.vs` hidden folder under the solution folder, `bin` and `obj` folder

**2)** delete all caches under `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_xxxx\ComponentModelCache`

**3)** Try to reset vs settings by **Tools**-->**Import and Export settings**-->**Reset All settings**--> **General**.

And if your VS has any other extensions, pleaese disable them under **Tools**-->**Extensions and Updates**

**After that**, check `Enable Javascript debuggigg for Asp.Net(Chrome,Edge and IE)` option

**4)** enable all options under **Tools**-->**Options**-->**Debugging**-->**Just-In-Time**

**5)** try to [clean Chrome caches](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32050?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) and then test again.

If it still does not help, please try to [reset settings in Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3296214?hl=en).

**Besides**, you could try to restart your PC.